# Replace Value of Variable

Tags: php

I have the below code snippet:

```
public function getShippingData()
{
    return array(
        'shipping_method' => $this->order->getShippingService(),
        'shipping_price'  => $this->getBaseShippingPrice(),
        'carrier_title'   => Mage::helper('M2ePro')->__('Amazon Shipping')
    );
}
```

I would like to change this to replace the value of shipping_method.  ie

```
if ($shipping_method == 'valuea') {
    $shipping_method = 'value1';
}

if ($shipping_method == 'something') {
    $shipping_method = 'somethingelse';
}
```

I have whole list of scenarios so depending on the value of shipping_method I want it to equal something else.  Is there a better way of achieving this rather than having 100's of if statements?

Comment: Lookup array - find key - replace with value. But really your `getShippingService` should return the result data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd make an array for this and replace the value based on a key.

```
$new_shipping_methods = array(
    'valueA' => 'value1',
    'valueB' => 'value2',
    // ...
);

$shipping_method = $new_shipping_methods[$shipping_method];
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [switch](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php) control structure. Is exactly what you need, different options depending on one variable, that eliminates a lot of if's.

Comment: Switch is certainly better for this scenario than multiple ifs, but you are still forced to repeat the context in each case block. The context is always the same here, it's replacing one value, so there are better ways.